# Using multiple slideToggle on one page

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, slidetoggle

I have used slideToggle to create a "dropdown" to display content when a link is clicked.

When "see opening times" is clicked, a div displaying times is shown.

Problem is, on my page there are multiple different locations with different opening times. SO by using one function, clicking the link opens ALL hidden divs. How can I link just one link to it's relevant div?

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ubPve/1/)

HTML:

```
    <div class="timeList">
    <a>See opening times</a>
    <p class="openingTimes" style="display: none;">
    <strong>Mon-Fri</strong>: 7am - 5.30pm<br />
    <strong>Sat</strong>:<br />
    <span class="seasonTimes"><em>Summer</em>: 7.30am - 5.30pm<br />
    </span>
    <span class="seasonTimes"><em>Winter</em>: 8am - 5pm<br />
    </span>
    <span class="seasonTimes"><em>November - March</em>: 8am - 1pm<br />
    </span>
    <strong>Sun</strong>: Closed
    </p>
    </div>
<br /><br />
 <div class="timeList">
    <a>See opening times</a>
    <p class="openingTimes" style="display: none;">
    <strong>Mon-Fri</strong>: 8am - 5.30pm<br />
    <strong>Sat</strong>:<br />
    <span class="seasonTimes"><em>Summer</em>: 90.30am - 5.30pm<br />
    </span>
    <span class="seasonTimes"><em>Winter</em>: 10am - 5pm<br />
    </span>
    <strong>Sun</strong>: 10am - 5.30pm
    </p>
    </div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(".timeList a").click(function () {
  $(".openingTimes").slideToggle("slow");
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `<p class="openingTimes">` element you want to toggle is the next sibling of the `<a>` that is handling the `click` event, so you can just use some simple DOM traversal to get a reference to the next element:

```
$('.timeList a').click(function(e) {
    $(this).next().slideToggle('slow');
});
```

Inside the function `this` is the actual DOM element for the anchor, `$(this)` creates a jQuery object that contains that element, `.next()` gets the element that comes after it in the DOM, and then obviously `.slideToggle('slow')` does the actual toggling.

You can, optionally, pass a selector to `.next()` to only select the next element if it also matches the selector. If you had multiple anchors inside each `<div class="timeList">` element then you might want to consider using:

```
$(this).next('.openingTimes').slideToggle('slow');
```

instead. Though with the HTML you've shown, that wouldn't be necessary.

Comment: Beat me to it...! I had the exact implementation

Answer (score 0):

problem with your code was.. you were selecting all div with class `openingtimes` and using slideToggle.. since bthe browser finds two this with call  `openingtimes`.. it slides both the divs...

you can use `$(this)` reference to get the clicked element and find the div `openingTimes` of that block and slide it

try this

```
$(this).parent().find(".openingTimes").slideToggle("slow");
```

OR

```
$(this).next().slideToggle("slow");
```

[working fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/bipen/ubPve/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Try the code given below

```
$(".timeList a").click(function () {
    $(this).parent('.timeList').children(".openingTimes").slideToggle("slow");
});
```